# uidialog sending the form multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery ui dialog with custom buttons that the first time sends the data fine, but when I click again on a newly opened dialog it sends twice, then three times and so on (without page reload). If I reload the page it works fine, but why? This is how my function looks:

```
function openPopup() {
     $('#box').dialog({
         autoOpen: true,
         modal   : true,
         title   : 'my title',
         width   : 500,
         open : function (event) {
            var dialog = $(this); 
            $(".buttonclass").live('click', function(event) {
                dialog.dialog('destroy');
                alert('hello'); //This alerts hello once first time, twice second time, etc.
            });
         },
         buttons : [
             {
                 text: 'Cancel',
                 click: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("destroy");
                 }
             }
         ]
     });
    }
```

What am I missing? I have been looking around and found stuff like click unbinding, dialog destroying, but none of those are working (as you can see i am destroying my dialog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use unbind before creating the click event. This is how the **open** part above should look like:

```
open : function (event) {
      var dialog = $(this); 
      $(".buttonclass").unbind('click').click(function(event) {
           dialog.dialog('destroy');
           alert('hello'); //This alerts hello once always now.
      });
},
```

That way, no extra clicks are binded to the button, and the form only sends once.